# I have a record template, it is creating well and when I open the edit template what I do is create a new record

Tags: html, django

I have the saveremission method, where the form that is in HTML creates it perfectly and loads it to the DB.

def guardarremision(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    fecharemi = request.POST['fecharemi']
    fechaenvio = request.POST['fechaenvio']
    clienteremi = request.POST['clienteremi']
    enviadoa = request.POST['enviadoa']
    fecharecibido = request.POST['fecharecibido']
    telefonoremi = request.POST['telefonoremi']
    formaenvio = request.POST['formaenvio']
    statusremi = request.POST['statusremi']
    preparadaremi = request.POST['preparadaremi']
    guiaremi = request.POST['guiaremi']

    remisiones = Remisiones(
        fecha = fecharemi,
        fecha_envio = fechaenvio,
        clientes_id = clienteremi,
        contacto = enviadoa,
        fecha_recibido = fecharecibido,
        telefono = telefonoremi,
        id_transporte_id = formaenvio,
        id_status = statusremi,
        elaborado = preparadaremi,
        guia = guiaremi
    )
    remisiones.save()


    return HttpResponse("Remision Creada")
else:
    return HttpResponse("Remision no puede ser creada")
```

When I go to edit I have the following method, I have another template with a form that brings all the information through the ID, but when I save the edition it creates a new record.

def editar_remision(request, id):
remision = Remisiones.objects.get(pk=id)

```
return render(request, "editar_remision.html", {
        'remision' : remision
    })
```

I try to upload the edit template but I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of save, use `update` method

```
# fetch the queryset containing the object that has to be edited.
qs = Remisiones.objects.filter(id = id)

qs.update(
    fecha = fecharemi,
    fecha_envio = fechaenvio,
    clientes_id = clienteremi,
    contacto = enviadoa,
    fecha_recibido = fecharecibido,
    telefono = telefonoremi,
    id_transporte_id = formaenvio,
    id_status = statusremi,
    elaborado = preparadaremi,
    guia = guiaremi
)
```

Or

```
# fetch the object related to the passed id
obj = get_object_or_404(Remisiones, id = id)

obj.fecha = fecharemi,
obj.fecha_envio = fechaenvio,
obj.clientes_id = clienteremi,
obj.contacto = enviadoa,
obj.fecha_recibido = fecharecibido,
obj.telefono = telefonoremi,
obj.id_transporte_id = formaenvio,
obj.id_status = statusremi,
obj.elaborado = preparadaremi,
obj.guia = guiaremi

obj.save()
```

Or If you are using the model form, pass the instance into the form

```
# fetch the object related to the passed id
obj = get_object_or_404(Remisiones, id = id)

# pass the object as an instance in the form
form = RemisionesForm(request.POST or None, instance = obj)

# save the data from the form and redirect to detail_view
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponse("Referencia actualizada")
```